# Controller not notified about final Job status

Tags: go, kubernetes, client-go, kubebuilder

I'm building an app that spawns Jobs (batch/v1), I need to update my Custom Resource status with the Job status.

I setup the controller with the following:

```golang
func (r *JobsManagedByRequestedBackupActionObserver) SetupWithManager(mgr ctrl.Manager) error {
    return ctrl.NewControllerManagedBy(mgr).
        For(&riotkitorgv1alpha1.RequestedBackupAction{}).
        Owns(&batchv1.Job{}).
        Owns(&batchv1.CronJob{}).
        WithEventFilter(predicate.Funcs{
            DeleteFunc: func(e event.DeleteEvent) bool {
                return false
            },
        }).
        Complete(r)
}
```

During the `Reconcile(ctx context.Context, req ctrl.Request)` I fetch my RequestedBackupAction object (basing on "req") and then I fetch Jobs from API using a dedicated tracking label.

```golang
list, err := kj.client.Jobs(namespace).List(ctx, metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: v1alpha1.LabelTrackingId + "=" + trackingId})
```

When I iterate over objects with:

```golang
for _, job := range list.Items {
        logrus.Errorf("[++++++++++++] JOB name=%s, failed=%v, active=%v, succeeded=%v", job.Name, job.Status.Failed, job.Status.Active, job.Status.Succeeded)
}
```

Then I get multiple entries like this:

```bash
time="2022-12-12T20:00:55Z" level=error msg="[++++++++++++] JOB name=app1-backup-vmqrp, failed=0, active=1, succeeded=0"
```

But I don't finally get an entry, where there should be: failed=1, active=0, succeeded=0
even if the Job actually finished - the point is that the controller is not being notified.

That's the final Job status:

```yaml
  status:
    conditions:
    - lastProbeTime: "2022-12-12T20:00:56Z"
      lastTransitionTime: "2022-12-12T20:00:56Z"
      message: Job has reached the specified backoff limit
      reason: BackoffLimitExceeded
      status: "True"
      type: Failed
    failed: 1
    ready: 0
    startTime: "2022-12-12T20:00:50Z"
    uncountedTerminatedPods: {}
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was really dead simple - when the object is not ready, then requeue it, wich for Job means to wait until it will be finished. Still I don't understand why the controller is not notified about a state change from: active=1 to active=0 and from failed=0 to failed=1

**Example:**

```golang
if healthStatus.Running {
    return ctrl.Result{Requeue: true}, nil
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the controller reference of your owned resources before creating?

The function `SetControllerReference` populates `metadata.ownerReferences` field of your owner resource with the parent resource's reference. Without setting owner reference, parent resource cannot be triggered by owned resource's change.

```golang
// instance is your custom resource
// job is the resource that supposed to be owned by instance

err = ctrl.SetControllerReference(instance, job, r.Scheme)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

err = r.Create(ctx, job)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```